# Several Errors being Logged for File I/O code

Tags: java, eclipse, file-io

Here is my code from learning the File i/o...

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UserFILE_IO {
    static FileInputStream fin;
    static FileOutputStream fout, fout1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            fin = new FileInputStream("ABC.txt");
            fout = new FileOutputStream("ABC.txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("FILE NOT FOUND!!!");
        }

        String s;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        s = sc.nextLine();

        try {
            fout.write(s.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {

            fout.close();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        sc.close();
        try {
            fout1 = new FileOutputStream("ABC1.txt");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            char c;
            while ((c = (char) fin.read()) != -1) {
                fout1.write(c);
                System.out.print(c);

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            fin.close();
            fout1.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to open the `ABC1.txt` file from the workspace folder (In C:), it shows the size of 12.00 MB and whenever I refresh  the folder the size also gets increased each time . And another thing I want to mention is, I m not able to see the File `ABC.txt` in the IDE (Eclipse) which I m using.

1. Why that file ABC1.txt is that larger of size 12.00 MB+
2. And why I m not able to get the ABC.txt file in my IDE?

Comment: Are you feeding the path for the ABC.txt in the input stream? I can not see it.

Comment: It will take the default path of the folder in which IDE will place the source code..

Comment: So is your ABC.txt in that folder?

Comment: yes it is visible in my workspace folder ..But can not be opened . it shows not responding ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also find it in the folder consisting the source code of your program inside that package.
Here as you have not mentioned the correct path to the file that where it is going to be stored then it must be the case of the default location . 
Try to write the path more precise.

Here the case may be like , abc.txt same file can also be overridden with contents of the file ABC.txt so , if there exist any file named abc.txt then ypu should also look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I got it!!!
Remove the class scope as public and mention as:

```
class UserFILE_IO{}
```

All you need to do is change the code as:

```
try{
    fout = new FileOutputStream("ABC.txt");
    fin = new FileInputStream("ABC.txt");
}
```

and finally change the loop as:

```
try {
    char c;
    while ((c = (char) fin.read()) == 1) {
        fout1.write(c);
        System.out.print(c);
    }
```

then you will get everything right.